# openapi.IN_FORM don't work with JSONParser in parser_classes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

When I changed `parser_classes=[MultiPartParser, FormParser]` to `parser_classes=[MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser]` I get an error when I open swagger:

```
drf_yasg.errors.SwaggerGenerationError: cannot add form parameters when the request has a request body; did you forget to set an appropriate parser class on the view?
```

I need my endpoint to be able to process multipart/formdata or application/json.
how can I do it in such code?:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(operation_description='desc',
                     manual_parameters=[
                            openapi.Parameter('phone',
                            openapi.IN_FORM,
                            description="phone",
                            type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
                            required=True),
                     ])
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): ...
```